# Access asp.net panel dynamically by Id

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have two drop down lists and one panel in my content page. The panel is not visible. What I want to achieve is when I choose the first item in the first drop down list, the second drop down list will change according to my first list's choice. I have done this part by storing the data into the database and retrieving the choices from the database.

Then, when I choose from the second drop down list, I wish to show the panel. I stored the panel name into database already. I can retrieve the panel name from the database, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

How can I get from that string (panel name) to the panel object and set Visible=true?

Comment: I hope I understand you fine, did you try do it from code behind ? pnlId.Visible = true

Comment: Maybe my explanation is worst. Procedure will be like this. Choose dropdownlist 1>dropdownlist 2>retrieve panel ID from database based on dropdownlist 1's choice and dropdownlist 2's choices > find that panel using the ID and set its visible to true. Step 1 to 3 is OK but I stuck at step 4. I just don't want hard code it..

Comment: Yes, so you want to access the panel by dynamic id

Comment: put the panel in other asp.net panel with id "pnlParent" or  div with runat="server" then in your code behind try  Panel pnl=(Panel)pnlParent.FindControl(your_dynamic_id); please try and let me know

Comment: Thank you so much it works.

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the panel in other asp.net panel with id `"pnlParent"` or div with `runat="server"` then in your code behind try :

```
Panel pnl=(Panel)pnlParent.FindControl(your_dynamic_id);
```